# Passing Multiple Parameters to an UIAlertAction in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I have been trying to find a way to pass multiple parameters to a UIAlertAction. Following is my code. I want to pass the "source" string to the joinSelected action of the alert.

I am getting an error like this:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) ->

```
fileprivate func showBetaAlert(source: String)  {
        let betaAlert =  UIAlertController.betaProgramAlert()
        let joinAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Join", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: joinSelected(alert: <#UIAlertAction#>, source: source))
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: cancelSelected)

        betaAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
        betaAlert.addAction(joinAction)

        present(betaAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

fileprivate func joinSelected(alert: UIAlertAction, source: String) {
        let betaAlert = UIAlertController.signUpAlert()
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: dismissEmailAction)
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default , handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let stelf = self else { return }
            let email = betaAlert.textFields![0] as UITextField
            stelf.submitAction(email: email.text!)
        })

        betaAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
        betaAlert.addAction(submitAction)

        present(betaAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You want to use the source string in side the handler of submitAction?

Comment: @HAK I tried to give the source string but  I am getting an error "Missing argument for parameter 'alert' in call"

Comment: Where in your `joinSelected` selected method do you even use the `alert` or `source` parameters?

Comment: You don't need to pass the source string as a parameter in the handler. Just use it inside the handler and it will be captured automatically for the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
let joinAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Join", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: joinSelected(alert: <#UIAlertAction#>, source: source))
```

with:

```
let joinAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Join", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
    joinSelected(source: source)
})
```

And update `joinSelected` to:

```
fileprivate func joinSelected(source: String) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Worked for me.